How to create a .well-know folder on Magento Cloud?
I want to create a mystore.com/.well-known folder on my Magento Cloud, where I can add many files that will be accessible via public URL.
How to do it?

You can do these simple steps below to do so.
1 - Create a new folder /pub/media/.well-know
2 - Add a VCL file in your Fastly config as below.
if (req.url.path ~ "/.well-known/([^/]+)") {
     set req.url  = "/media/well_known/" re.group.1;
}

